# How to use BeforeMethod output in Test Method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

My @BeforeMethod generates an output.

```
@BeforeMethod
public  void Random() throws Exception {
    //Generating Random Text
    int leftLimit = 97; 
    int rightLimit = 122; 
    int targetStringLength = 3;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(targetStringLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < targetStringLength; i++) {
        int randomLimitedInt = leftLimit + (int) 
          (new Random().nextFloat() * (rightLimit - leftLimit));
        buffer.append((char) randomLimitedInt);
    }
    String generatedString = buffer.toString();

    System.out.println(generatedString);


}
```

How can I use the output of the @BeforeMethod in below method

```
@Test(priority = 1)
    public  void Registration() throws Exception {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[2]/UIATextField[1]")).sendKeys("abc" + generatedString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your question would be to store the generated string in a class level variable (field). For example decalring `private String generatedString` at the class level and setting `generatedString` in your before method.

However, because all you're doing in your before method is generating a random string, it would make more sense to have your random generating method just be a regular method that can be called from any where in the class.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void registration() throws Exception {
    String randomString = generateRandomString();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[2]/UIATextField[1]")).sendKeys("abc" + randomString);
}

public String generateRandomString() throws Exception {
    //Generating Random Text
    int leftLimit = 97; 
    int rightLimit = 122; 
    int targetStringLength = 3;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(targetStringLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < targetStringLength; i++) {
        int randomLimitedInt = leftLimit + (int) (new Random().nextFloat() * (rightLimit - leftLimit));
        buffer.append((char) randomLimitedInt);
    }
    String generatedString = buffer.toString();

    System.out.println(generatedString);

    return generatedString;
}
```

I should also mention that there are many good libraries that have solutions for generating random strings.  Apache's `RandomStringUtils` class is an example.

**EDIT:** In response to the below question of only generating one random string:

```
private final static String RANDOM_STRING = generateRandomString();

@Test(priority = 1)
public void registration() throws Exception {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[2]/UIATextField[1]")).sendKeys("abc" + RANDOM_STRING);
}

public String generateRandomString() throws Exception {
    //Generating Random Text
    int leftLimit = 97; 
    int rightLimit = 122; 
    int targetStringLength = 3;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(targetStringLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < targetStringLength; i++) {
        int randomLimitedInt = leftLimit + (int) (new Random().nextFloat() * (rightLimit - leftLimit));
        buffer.append((char) randomLimitedInt);
    }
    String generatedString = buffer.toString();

    System.out.println(generatedString);

    return generatedString;
}
```

Comment: when I add a new Test method it is generating a new random text...How can I use the same text which is generated first.

Comment: @ArunKumar i updated my answer to reuse the same generated string